# Send variables to all routes in exressjs

Tags: node.js, express

Using nodejs/expressjs to build the APIs for my web app, I want to send some variables to all APIs, such as site title and description and so on.

I stumbled upon the old solution using dynamicHelper() which is no longer in use. What is the new approach to do so?

Comment: There's simply not enough detail in this question for us to answer.  What does "send some variables to all APIs" mean?  Is every single route in your server an API or are some routes doing things other than the API?  What code are you using to construct your API responses?  Are you returning JSON?  What do your API responses look like?  Can you show us the code for a typical API response and show us the actual response with your special variables added?  What type of variables to you want to add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest thing is to just put in some middleware that attaches it to the response object as locals (those will show up in your views automatically).  Something like:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
   res.locals = {
     title : 'your title',
     description : 'your description'
   };
   return next();
});
```

** EDIT to account for what the API endpoints have to do
Since each endpoint is likely responsible for its own object, you would also do something like:

```
app.get('/whatever', function(req,res){
   var json = {}; 
    // do whatever to build your json
   json.metadata = res.locals; // or whatever the common stuff is
   res.send(json);
}
```

This keeps all your 'common' stuff in one part of the json response.

Comment: I am using angularjs for everything in the front-end, and the expressjs app is only for APIs. Therefore not using the view engine in express.

Comment: @JoshuaLeung - If you have more requirements such as you just mentioned, then PUT those details into your question.  Your question lacks enough detail for anyone to know how to answer properly.

Comment: But I already said "Using nodejs/expressjs to build the APIs for my web app" as the first thing in the paragraph...

Comment: I'm not sure this changes my answer.  You asked how to make it available to every endpoint; my answer does so.  You can then merge that object with whatever response the endpoint is sending to the client. The fact that it'll work if you're using a view engine is nice to know whether or not you need that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention you are not using any view engine in expressjs, I am assuming you are just relying on angularJS to do the client side redering. You can pass those server side data to the http header, and then read them from the client side. To do that, in your router, you can do this,

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
    res.set({
      'title': 'my title',
      'description': '123'
    });
    next();
});
```

Then in your angularJS app, you can read them from the http header.

Answer (score -1):

You should try [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in your front end side(angular js) to send multiple variable with each request api.

In following code i am sending title and description in headers.

```
module.factory('varInfoInterceptors',  function($q) {  
    var sendInfoInjector = {
        request: function(config) {
                config.headers['x-headers-title'] = 'Test title';
                config.headers['x-headers-desc'] = 'This is test site';
            return config;
        }
    };
    return sendInfoInjector;
});
module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('varInfoInterceptors');
}]);
```

You can get these values in server side(nodejs/expressjs) by just calling **req.headers** [express](http://expressjs.com/) routes

Thanks,

Dinesh